# How do you start off with implementing a thread library?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

How to write kernel code in C ? Where can we look forward to learn more of writing kernel code ? I want to know writing programs in C that can be used to modify my kernel. How do i do that ? What resources can i look upto ?

Comment: Perhaps you could specify what particular kind of modifications of the kernel you would like to do, in order to get a better answer.

Comment: What makes you think thread libraries modify the kernel? What are you actually trying to do? The kernel already provides the building blocks that a thread library requires - look at the pthread source for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a good Operating Systems text like [Operating Systems Concepts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720) for some good theoretical background. That's important.

Check out [Robert Love's Excellent Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327201) about linux kernel programming for some good practical background. That may be even more important.